# How to add a custom order field to checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, sales-order, extension-attributes, mixins

I'm looking for the best (i.e. recommended) way to add a custom `order` field in the **billing step** of the checkout page.

### Requirements

In particular, I'd like to add a **fast delivery** option. If the customer opts in, the package will be shipped faster for an extra fee.

The `fast_delivery` attribute is gonna be an [extension attribute](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/add-attributes/) of the `Order` entity. It will be persisted in the `fast_delivery` table. This table has a 1:1 relationship to the `sales_order` table.

### No place in payload of `place-order` action

I've gone through the [checkout customization tutorials](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/tutorials/frontend/custom-checkout/) in the official docs. However, I've not found any example on how to save additional order data in particular – just how to extend shipping address, payment and such stuff.

First, I thought attaching the value of the fast delivery field to the JSON payload of `POST /carts/mine/payment-information` (which is the request that's placing the order) would be the way to go. For that, I would implement a *mixin* for [place-order.js](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/action/place-order.js). However, the JSON object of that call has the following structure:

```
{
  "billingAddress": { ... },
  "cartId": "12345",
  "paymentMethod": { ... }
}
```

There's no obvious place to add the fast_delivery option. Of course, I could "abuse" `paymentMethod.extension_attributes`. But that doesn't feel right since fast delivery is not a concern of payment.

#### How about adding a fourth key to the JSON object?

Doesn't seem to work either because the method [savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/7c6b6365a3c099509d6f6e6c306cb1821910aab0/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Api/PaymentInformationManagementInterface.php#L24), which is handling the request on the server-side, has exactly three parameters: `$cartId`, `$paymentMethod` and `$billingAddress`. I am not aware of a way to change the signature of an API interface.

### Additional Ajax requests

When looking for other solutions, I stumbled upon an [article](https://bsscommerce.com/blog/add-magento-custom-checkout-fields/) suggesting to issue an additional Ajax request – also in a mixin of `place-order.js`.

On the server-side, a custom REST endpoint stores the value in the `quote` table. When the order is submitted, an [`observer`](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/events-and-observers/) copies the value to the `order` entity.

The **1st problem**: There's **no proper way of error handling** when the additional request fails.

This is quite clear: due to the nature of asynchronous requests, there's no guarantee that the additional request (i.e. the one saving the fast delivery option) is gonna be finished before the main one. So if the "fast delivery option"-request fails, and the main one is faster, the order would be placed even though the additional request failed.

That leads to the **2nd problem**: If the additional request is absolutely necessary to fulfill the order, and if it fails, we gonna end up with corrupt orders that can't be fulfilled.

### Recommended way?

Isn't there an official, recommended way of doing this?